# Speed up TCL lsearch for long list of long strings

Tags: tcl

I am globbing files with wildcards in the files system. To avoid double counting I use a list of files that I have already captured and then lserach to check. Now the names of the full file paths are pretty long and I am coming to thousands of files. The lsearch lookup is getting really slow.

In simplified version it looks like this.

```
foreach fn  [ glob $pattern ] {
    if {[lsearch $done $fn] == -1} {
        lappend done $fn
        # Do somethig with $fn
    } else {
        #puts "Duplicate fn not processed."
    }
}
```

Over time the lsearch has to look up pretty longs strings in a longer and longer list. What can be done to improve this? I was thinking to make the strings shorter by using some sort of CRC and putting that into the done list.  But the fingerprint computation shouldn't take longer than the search.

Answer (score 1):

There are two options, providing you are only ever interested in whether a literal string is present or not (that seems likely to me since the patterns are coming from `glob`):

1. If you can ensure that the list that you are searching against is alphabetically sorted, `lsearch -sorted` is much faster (O(log n) in the size of the data rather than O(n); it does a binary search). The one-time cost of sorting the list might be worthwhile.
2. If you only really care whether the value is present or not, you can load the list entries into a dictionary or array as keys; checking for presence of a value then (`dict exists` or `info exists`) is a very cheap operation, even with a lot of data. Under the covers, dicts and arrays are hash tables and so are highly suited to this sort of thing.

If you're building the list piecemeal as a check against repeating work (sounds like you are) then option 2 is absolutely the best one.

Answer (score 0):

I found the better idea to append all into the list first and then uniquify at the end. So only one pass through the list is needed.

```
set all_fn {}
foreach fn $files {
    regsub {stuff} $fn {stuff_with_wildcards} pattern
    set all_fn [concat $all_fn [ glob $pattern ] ]
}
set all_fn_u [ lsort -unique $all_fn ]
foreach fn $all_fn_u {
    #Do something with $fn
}
```

Comment: Pls. re-read Donal's answer carefully. You seem to have missed the point. Btw. there are more than "one pass" involved in your example.

Answer (score 0):

To follow up on Donal's suggestion:

> you can load the list entries into a dictionary or array as keys

```
set d [dict create {*}[string cat [join [glob {*}$patterns] " _ "] " _"]]
foreach fn [dict keys $d] {
  puts $fn
}
```

- [`glob`](https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl/TclCmd/glob.htm) can work on multiple patterns at a time, no need for feeding only one at a time.
- Create an even-sized list of elements (its string representation) from glob's results using [`join`](https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl/TclCmd/join.htm).
- Load the resulting string rep of a Tcl list into a dictionary using `dict create`.
- Use `dict keys` to obtain the (unique) list of keys.

Comment: Some care is due when `glob` can return an empty list of results.

Comment: This is also vulnerable to filenames that contain whitespace. You might want to do: `set d {}; foreach file [glob $pattern] {dict set d $file _}`

Comment: I tend to agree, likely an explicit loop is more robust here; however, filenames w/ whitespaces could be accommodated like so: `string cat "{" [join [glob {*}$patterns] "} _ {"] "}"`